# What are the key features to look for in choosing an open source "webhook server"

Tags: performance, webhooks

I'm developing a solution that will offer clients web-hook callbacks, or simply web-hooks.

1) are there sample implementations one can derive from

2) what can i do to ensure that my clients receive data only from my service and are not spoofed

3) i expect that most of my clients will have high latency (slow) urls for me to deliver callbacks - what can i do to mitigate this especially under high volume messaging and still provide a scalable service.

My primary development environment is .net on windows.

thanks.